# from_utf8 wraps string in quotations

Tags: string, utf-8, rust

I am currently learning rust by building a simple tool.

I need to concatenate, some scripts and was using rust-embed. The crate returns a borrowed &[u8] for a given file, and I need to interpret that as string.

From rust [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/fn.from_utf8.html),
I have the following [example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=%23!%5Ballow(unused)%5D%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0Ause%20std%3A%3Astr%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20some%20bytes%2C%20in%20a%20vector%0Alet%20sparkle_heart%20%3D%20vec!%5B240%2C%20159%2C%20146%2C%20150%5D%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20We%20know%20these%20bytes%20are%20valid%2C%20so%20just%20use%20%60unwrap()%60.%0Alet%20sparkle_heart%20%3D%20str%3A%3Afrom_utf8(%26sparkle_heart).unwrap()%3B%0A%0Aassert_eq!(%22%F0%9F%92%96%22%2C%20sparkle_heart)%3B%0A%7D&edition=2018).

```rust
#![allow(unused)]
fn main() {
use std::str;

// some bytes, in a vector
let sparkle_heart = vec![240, 159, 146, 150];

// We know these bytes are valid, so just use `unwrap()`.
let sparkle_heart = str::from_utf8(&sparkle_heart).unwrap();

println!("I {:?} U", &sparkle_heart);
}
```

The output is

```sh
I "" U
```

My issue is the quotations around the heart, which causes issues in my final script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `from_utf8`.

You are using the `Debug` (because your format is `{:?}`), which is meant for debugging and always surrounds strings by quotes and escape special characters.

You instead should use `{}`:

```rust
println!("I {} U", &sparkle_heart);
```

which will print `I  U`.

See also:

- [The documentation of the `std::fmt` module](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html)

Comment: Thank you! I didnt even notice that, since the examples in rust-embed use this.

Comment: Side note: if all you want is to include Unicode characters in a string, you can use a [Unicode escape sequence](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/tokens.html#character-escapes) instead of formatting from raw bytes: `"I \u{1F496} U"`. Or if your editor permits, you can simply write the Unicode characters directly in the code: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1516d912c5d95a341c0d133356f1d064).